# EventHubTrigger C# with EventData object

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-eventhub

I am using 1x functions, my question is, if with this version, I can receive an object of type EventData.

I have read documentation about it, but it has not been clear to me.

When executing the function, throw the following exception:

> mscorlib: Exception while executing function: eventHubTest. 
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Se han producido uno o varios errores. Exception binding parameter 'myEventHubMessage'. 
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Binding parameters to complex objects (such as 'EventData') uses Json.NET serialization.
>   1. Bind the parameter type as 'string' instead of 'EventData' to get the raw values and avoid JSON deserialization, or
>   2. Change the queue payload to be valid json. The JSON parser failed: Unable to find a constructor to use for type Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.EventData. 
>   A class should either have a default constructor, one constructor with arguments or a constructor marked with the JsonConstructor attribute. Path 'Origen', line 1, position 10.

This is the header of the function:

```
using Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs;

[FunctionName("FunctionTest")]
     public static void Run(
         [EventHubTrigger("eventHubTest", Connection = "EventHubConnectionString", ConsumerGroup = "%EventHubConsumerGroup%")]
         EventData[] myEventHubMessage,
         ILogger log)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose I reproduce your problem. In my test if If I use the `EventData` class in `Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs` package, it will cause this problem. Then after test I find it should be `Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.EventData`, so my solution is change the `EventData` reference to `Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging`, then it will solve this problem.

The below is my work code, you could refer to it.

```
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using System.Text;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus;
using Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;

namespace FunctionApp14
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task RunAsync([EventHubTrigger("geoevent", Connection = "eventcon",ConsumerGroup = "geogroup")]EventData[] events, TraceWriter log)
        {

            var exceptions = new List<Exception>();

            foreach (EventData eventData in events)
            {
                try
                {
                    string messageBody = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(eventData.GetBytes());

                    // Replace these two lines with your processing logic.
                    log.Info($"C# Event Hub trigger function processed a message: {messageBody}");
                    await Task.Yield();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    // We need to keep processing the rest of the batch - capture this exception and continue.
                    // Also, consider capturing details of the message that failed processing so it can be processed again later.
                    exceptions.Add(e);
                }
            }

            // Once processing of the batch is complete, if any messages in the batch failed processing throw an exception so that there is a record of the failure.

            if (exceptions.Count > 1)
                throw new AggregateException(exceptions);

            if (exceptions.Count == 1)
                throw exceptions.Single();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the anwser, but Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.EventData and Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.EventData, are distinct objects.

Comment: @Skymett,Check the [class description](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.eventdata?view=azure-dotnet), it could be used to receive event from event hub.

Comment: Yes, with Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.EventData, I receive the body of the message, but I was interested in obtaining the PartitionKey, which in this case I always receive at null. I wanted to try Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.EventData to see if PartitionKey brings any value

Comment: @Skymett, I suppose you could get the PartitionKey with the [metadata binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs?tabs=csharp#trigger---event-metadata). If this could help you, you could accept it as thne answer. Thanks!